# how to get all the primary key from a database

Tags: oracle

I am searching for a query or a way where I can export all the primary key in the database
I have more than 1000+ primary key.

I can use such way

```
select ' alter table '''||tab1||''' add constraint '''||constraint_name|||''' primary key values ( '''||columns||''' ') from user_cons_tables
```

but the problem in the above is that I cannot added more that one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on 11g and have the `listagg` function available you can use that. I don't know what `user_cons_tables` is in your example, but this does what you want, I think:

```
select ' alter table "' || uc.table_name || '" add constraint "'
  ||uc.constraint_name||'" primary key ('||
    listagg('"' || column_name || '"', ',') within group (order by ucc.position)
  || ')' as alter_statement
from user_constraints uc
join user_cons_columns ucc on ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
where uc.constraint_type = 'P'
group by uc.table_name, uc.constraint_name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c247/1)

But why roll your own? You can use `dbms_metadata` instead:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('CONSTRAINT', uc.constraint_name)
from user_constraints uc 
where uc.constraint_type = 'P';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c247/3)

You might want to do some transformations to remove the storage etc., as I've shown in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Use DBMS_METADATA package:

```
SQL> col x format a100
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('CONSTRAINT', constraint_name) x
  2  from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'P' and rownum <= 2
  3  /

X                                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SCOTT"."TEST_TAB" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("X")                            
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS             
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE                                              


  ALTER TABLE "SCOTT"."T" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "NAME")                                                                             
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS             
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645         
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1                                   
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)             
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
```